# iOS: How to Implement a "Shake Device" event?

Tags: ios, shake

I want to a "Shake Device" event to my app - i.e., when the user shakes the device something happens.
I tried implementing:

```
-(void) motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) {
        //something happens
    }
}
```

It doesn't seem to work.......
Does anyone knows which method I should use?

Answer (score 5):

Try using the below code, it worked fine for me.

```
- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if ( event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake )
       {
          //your code
       }

    if ( [super respondsToSelector:@selector(motionEnded:withEvent:)] )
                [super motionEnded:motion withEvent:event];
}
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be to late to answer but in your viewDidLoad you need to include.

```
[self becomeFirstResponder];
```

Give that a try.

Comment: also you have to add... -(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder{return YES;}

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Taylor's solution, also make sure that your AppDelegate.m has this in it.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    application.applicationSupportsShakeToEdit = YES;
    return YES;
}
```